# PostgreSQL: Disk space not released after TRUNCATE

Tags: postgresql, truncate, disk-space

I have`TRUNCATE`d a huge (~120Gb) table called `files`:

```
TRUNCATE files;
VACUUM FULL files;
```

The table size is 0, but no disk space was released. Any ideas how to reclaim my lost disk space?

**UPDATE:**
The disk space was released after ~12 hours, without any action on my side. I use Ubuntu 8.04 server.

Comment: I was about to suggest "vacuum it!", but considering you just did, I'd advise taking this over to either of the pg-hackers or pg-performance lists (and linking back to the thread or answer once you've got one).

Comment: Does this link (http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/TRUNCATE-timing-of-the-return-of-disk-space-caused-by-long-lived-client-tp1890800p1890801.html) give any advice for you? Maybe there is still something accessing the table or similar.

Comment: @DrColossos: I read a comment in the source (a comment which I can't find right now) that said PostgreSQL notified all the connections that a truncate was about to take place, and it locked the necessary resources. (There are several, including the table itself, indexes, sequences, and toast tables.) I'm pretty sure I found the comment earlier by tracing through ExecuteTruncate(), but I'm not 100% positive about that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [comments in the source](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/tablecmds_8h.html), `truncate` creates a new, empty storage file, and deletes the old storage file at commit time. (Docs suggest "storage file" is just a file as far as the OS is concerned, but I might be misunderstanding the terminology.)

> Create a new empty storage file for
>   the relation, and assign it as the
>   relfilenode value. The old storage
>   file is scheduled for deletion at
>   commit.

Since it seems to be deleting a file, I can imagine some cases in which the underlying operating system might not immediately free that space. I imagine that in some cases the storage file might end up in the Recycling Bin under Windows, for example. But in my case, truncating a table under PostgreSQL 9.something immediately increased the freespace under Windows.

Truncation is also recorded in the WAL log. I don't know how much effect that might have.

Comment: It's conceivable that another backend process still has a file descriptor to the file open.  If this happens again, I'd try terminating all other backend processes, just to see whether it makes a difference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read that ExecuteTruncate() is supposed to make sure that can't happen. All part of locking the resources necessary to eventually delete the old storage file. But I don't know where I found that in the source. I'm just browsing it online; it's easy to get lost that way.