# External size of table still not released (as disk space) after issuing truncate command

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, disk-space, truncate

In PostgreSQL 9.3.10 (Ubuntu 14.04 OS), I have a table called `groupseen` whose size is as follows:

```
              Table               |  Size   | External Size 
----------------------------------+---------+---------------
          links_groupseen         | 394 MB  | 362 MB
```

I understand that `External Size` is the size that related objects of this table (like indices) take.

Upon issuing the command `truncate links_groupseen;`, only `394 MB` disk space was released (I checked right after, via `df -h`). My two questions are:

1. What can I do to get rid of the space taken up by this table's indices (`External Size`) as well? Shouldn't `truncate` have taken care of everything?
2. I was using the following command to check the size of this table. Even though `External Size` hasn't yet been released, using [this command](https://wiki-bsse.ethz.ch/display/ITDOC/Check+size+of+tables+and+objects+in+PostgreSQL+database) now doesn't show the outstanding `362 MB`. How do I monitor the outstanding `External Size` related to this table?

   ```
   SELECT
      relname as "Table",
      pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Size",
      pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid) - pg_relation_size(relid)) as "External Size"
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables
    ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;
   ```

In case required, here's how the table looks like:

```
                            Table "public.links_groupseen"
     Column     |           Type           |                          Modifiers                           
----------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                  | not null default nextval('links_groupseen_id_seq'::regclass)
 seen_user_id   | integer                  | not null
 seen_at        | timestamp with time zone | not null
 which_reply_id | integer                  | not null
Indexes:
    "links_groupseen_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "links_groupseen_seen_user_id" btree (seen_user_id)
    "links_groupseen_which_reply_id" btree (which_reply_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "links_groupseen_seen_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (seen_user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "links_groupseen_which_reply_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_reply_id) REFERENCES links_reply(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

---

Note: [this SO answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/postgresql-disk-space-not-released-after-truncate) doesn't solve  my problem because the OP in the question stated how disk space wasn't released for him **at all**. In my case, the subtlety is that only `External Size` is outstanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL: Disk space not released after TRUNCATE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/postgresql-disk-space-not-released-after-truncate)

Comment: Did you `vacuum full`?

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Nope, because I don't need to do I? You yourself told me a couple of months ago that `TRUNCATE removes the entire content of the table immediately, without requiring a subsequent VACUUM or VACUUM FULL to reclaim the now-unused disk space.` Source: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160760/releasing-disk-space-by-using-delete-or-truncate

Comment: I don't think you need it, I'm just wondering if you have the backend xid open and if that catches it, no idea. restarting the service should work too not sure what's keeping the file open or why your os isn't reaping it.

Comment: Note that while I don't think it's needed, I would be interested to see what VACUUM FULL VERBOSE says if anything when it tries to clean up the relation

Answer (score 2):

I think with a truncate even without a `VACUUM FULL` the space is released back to the OS. My guess is [per the other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/postgresql-disk-space-not-released-after-truncate) that you've got a backend process holding the underlying file open.

1. Find out what the file is. `SELECT pg_relation_filepath('links_groupseen');`
2. Find the data directory `SHOW data_directory;`
3. Run truncate.
4. See what's holding it open. `lsof $data_directory/$relation_filepath`

I think the most likely bet is something is holding it open if not, we'll have to know whether or not Pg is deleting the underlying `relation_filepath` before and after the truncate command and if anything has that file open (if it exists). You may have to run `lsof` before the truncate too.

Comment: **1** yields `base/30137/32955673`. **2** yields `/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main`. I ran `lsof /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/base/30137/32955673` before and after running `truncate links_groupseen;`. Both times, there wasn't any output. Guess I'll next try `VACUUM FULL VERBOSE`

Comment: Hmm, so doing `vacuum full verbose links_groupseen;` just gave me `INFO:  vacuuming "public.links_groupseen"
INFO:  "links_groupseen": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
CPU 0.00s/0.00u sec elapsed 0.01 sec.
VACUUM
`

Comment: @HassanBaig if you only truncated the file, it's possible all of those are pointing to the new file, and not the old one.

Comment: What's the best way to retrieve the current size of these incidences? (so we can be sure they still exist). This was actually part of my question as well.

Answer (score 0):

The 394 MB is the total size, **inclusive** of external items like indexes and toast tables.  If 394 MB is what you saw getting released, then that is all there is.

Comment: Could you provide a documented source for that assertion? The way it's described here, that doesn't seem to be the case: https://wiki-bsse.ethz.ch/display/ITDOC/Check+size+of+tables+and+objects+in+PostgreSQL+database

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-admin.html: "Total disk space used by the specified table, including all indexes and TOAST data"